# Erlang binary concatenation

Tags: erlang

so i have these following 
`A = <<1:1>>` and `B = <<1>>.`
Any built in function(or couple of lines of code) to join these two binaries, which total size should be **16 bits** ?

Have already tried following:

```
C = <<B/binary,A:8/bitstring>>.
C = <<B/binary,A:8/binary>>.
C = <<B/binary,A:8>>.
C = <<B/binary,A/bitstring>>.
```

This works but the size will be 9 bits long.

P.S I dont want 8 lines of erlang code as a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably need to add some padding:

```
<< B/binary, 0:7, A/bitstring >>.
```